# Access SVN files from Http

Tags: svn

I have installed svn in `/var/svn`
My webroot is : `/srv/mydomain.com/public_html`

How can I see my svn project `/var/svn/myproject` from `http://ip:8000` ?
WebDav is installed and httpd.conf is empty.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the tutorials:

http://csoft.net/docs/svndav.html.en